# Add delimiter for up to the first two groups of two numbers with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression that adds a separator every two numbers the first and second time I have the error in these cases:

```
str.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1/$2/')

entered value   result          expectation
1               ✓
22              x(22)              22/
222             x(222)             22/2
2222            ✓(22/22/)
22222           ✓(22/22/2)
222222          ✓(22/22/22)
 ...
22222222222     ✓(22/22/2222222)
```

How can I solve these two error cases?

Comment: you want `22/22/2222222` and not `22/22/22/22/22/2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a good way to do this with a simple replacement alone. I'd use a callback: match up to 2 digits in the second group, and only insert the second `/` if both digits are matched:

```js
const change = str => str.replace(
  /^(\d{2})(\d{0,2})/,
  (_, g1, g2) => `${g1}/${g2 + (g2.length === 2 ? '/' : '')}`
);
console.log(change('2'));
console.log(change('22'));
console.log(change('222'));
console.log(change('2222'));
console.log(change('22222'));
console.log(change('222222'));
```

Or call `.replace` twice:

```js
const change = str => str
  .replace(/^\d{4}/, '$&/')
  .replace(/^\d{2}/, '$&/');
console.log(change('2'));
console.log(change('22'));
console.log(change('222'));
console.log(change('2222'));
console.log(change('22222'));
console.log(change('222222'));
```